# How to solve - Failed to execute operation: Too many levels of symbolic links on CentOs 7

Tags: centos, symlink, nginx

I am trying to install `erpNext` on a CentOS 7.4 VPS and I'm following the installation script [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/axatec/MIS-ERPNEXT-ScriptInstall/master/setup_frappe.sh). But I get this error during installation:

```
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
Configuring CentOS services
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nginx.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service.
Failed to execute operation: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

How I do I fix this error? My guess is there's a problem with the setup file but I'm new to this so I don't know where to look.

Comment: My guess is that /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nginx.service is a symlink to /usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service which is also a symlink.

Answer (score -1):

This is because your service is using symbolic link so remove symbolic link and try.

It should work

Comment: How to remove symbolic links?